# Simple MySQL query not working as hoped

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running this query, I need to find out the longest string in a given field, so I can make sure it doesn't wrap when displayed on the front-end.

```
#The query is:
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(fullname)), fullname FROM soft_data;
```

What I expected was something like: 58 "string of 58 character length"

What I got was:41 "string of 27 character length"

```
max(char_length(fullname)), fullname
41  Zoom Player Professional 7
```

I hope I've explained well enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(fullname)
     , fullname 
FROM soft_data
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(fullname) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `order by CHAR_LENGTH(fullname) desc` to the end of your query.

Comment: What explains the ""What I got was:41 "string of 27 character length""" ?

Comment: @Pheonix: in MySQL, when including unaggregated items in grouped result sets, the value on the **first** record within the group is returned in the resultset - without any ordering, this will essentially be a random value.